# jQuery List Scroll on Hover with Flexslider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins, flexslider

My problem is that I can't get the ol element to scroll on hover without the image on the right also scrolling. I know it's probably something simple. I just don't know what it is.

I've been working on this for quite a bit of time and can't seem to figure this out. There are multiple jQuery plugins that add scrolling on hover for vertical thumbnails, but none of them support the Flexslider HTML structure. That's my biggest dilemma.

The basic structure for the flexslider is as follows:

```
<div id="flexslider-object" class="flexslider">
    <ul class="slides">
        <li><img></li>
        <li><img></li>
        <li><img></li>
    </ul>
    <ol class="flex-control-thumbs">
        <li><a><img></a></li>
        <li><a><img></a></li>
        <li><a><img></a></li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

All of the plugins I've tried working with a vertical list all ruin the structure which ruins the synchronization between the flexslider main image and the thumbnails. So, the structure needs to stay intact.

At the current point, I have gotten the list to scroll as I hover on each end of the list. However, the main image is also scrolling which doesn't need to happen. Here's the script I have for it already:

```
$.fn.thumbScroller = function () {
    var div = $(this),
            wrapScreenHeight = div.height(),
            top = div.offset().top,
            $list = div.find('ol'),
            wrapHeight = div.outerHeight(),
            listHeight = div.find('ol').outerHeight() * 1.3;
    $list.on('mousemove', function (e) {
        var cPointY = e.pageY - top,
                dP = ((cPointY / wrapHeight));

        div.animate({scrollTop: (listHeight * dP) - wrapScreenHeight}, 1);
    });
};
$('#flexslider-object').thumbScroller();
```

I couldn't get this to work in jsfiddle, so I posted it on my dev site. 
http://dev.blahalife.com/flexslider_thumbs/

You can view the source to check it the code.
view-source:http://dev.blahalife.com/flexslider_thumbs/

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that the right side image should not scroll? and it should shows the image which has mouse over on left side

Comment: Correct. My objective is to be able to scroll through the list of images on the left while the image on the right should not move. Syncing up the thumbnails with the main image will be done once I implement it into the site I'm working on.

Answer (score 0):

here you go buddy check this and than tell me

[https://www.dropbox.com/s/wktlpq9925s9aud/stackoverflow.rar?dl=0][1]

Comment: Thanks for that. That's not exactly what I need though. What I was saying about the HTML structure is that it has to stay in the same structure like I mentioned in the original post. So, I have to do something different with the jQuery or cSS. I'm not sure where at this point.